# Read 'm-to-n' row numbers from a txt file (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, file-io, row, text-files

I'm trying to read data from a .txt file.  The sample data is given below.  I need an algorithm to read just M-N row numbers.  While I can use while/for loops, I'm afraid that it might become very slow.  Thanks!

```
a=[  1 6 11 16 ; 
     2 7 12 17 ; 
     3 8 13 18 ; 
     4 9 14 19 ; 
     5 10 15 20] ;    % data is in Test.txt --> 
                      % fid = fopen('Test.txt');
                      % a=a.'; fprintf(fid, '%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\r\n', a(:)) ;

fid = fopen('Test.txt') ;
AnsMat = fscanf(fid, '%f %f %f %f')

AnsMat = [2 7 12 17 ; 3 8 13 18] ;  % Read row-numbers 2 to 4 this time
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) which allows a `HeaderLines` parameter telling matlab how many lines to skip.

For example to read lines n (=2) to m(=4), you could do:

```
fid = fopen('Test.txt');
C   = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f\n',m-n+1,'HeaderLines',n-1);
fclose(fid);
```

This does return the data as a cell array though so you have to convert it:

```
AnsMat = cell2mat(C);
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks but that doesn't work because 'm-n+1' fetches data column wise and not row wise.  Its important that I get the data row-wise.  Can you please suggest another approach, or delete this solution?

Comment: Can you then give some context as to why the data must be row-wise? Using `cell2mat` will convert your data into a matrix, after which you can apply row-wise operations. And if you were only reading one line in at a time (say it was a loop), you'd just read in one line the first time with skip `n-1` and `1` instead of `m-n+1`, and in the subsequent loops you can just use `fscanf` (since the file handle now points to the rows you're interested in, so there's no need to skip any more).

Comment: oops!! sorry!  I had done a=a.' and so I was verifying it wrong.  Thanks so much.  This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

If your data were in csv format instead of text format, you could use the command:

```
text=csvread('yourfile.csv',1,1,[1 1 m n])
```

Obviously, if your data is only available in text format, it would be just as much work to manually convert it as it would be to use the textscan option, but if your text file is being generated elsewhere where you would have control over the output format, this may streamline the process.

Comment: Thanks Prototoast.  As of now the file is in .txt, but if I ever get it in csv, your solution would be perfect.